# File path not saved in database, but it is in storage. Collision? Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-storage

Hey im trying to handle file upload with use of celery tasks. However after all tasks complete, file appears to be in storage and not in database when i query /files. Thumbnail (which is generated as second task, but is much faster) is both saved in storage and database. What could be the issue?

views.py

```py
@extend_schema(
        description="Upload file",
        request=FileSerializer,
        responses={201: FileSerializer},
    )
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        file = request.data["file"]

        total_sum = File.objects.filter(owner=request.user).aggregate(models.Sum("size"))
        total_sum = total_sum["size__sum"] if total_sum["size__sum"] else 0

        if total_sum + file.size > request.user.storage_limit:
            return Response(
                {"error": "Storage limit exceeded"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )

        request.data["size"] = file.size

        serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(owner=request.user, size=file.size)
            FileService.upload_file(serializer.data["id"], file.read(), file.content_type)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

services.py

```py
import base64
import mimetypes
from common.service import Service
from storage.tasks import UploadHandler, ThumbnailHandler


class FileService(Service):  # Service is empty class, just class Service: ...
    handlers = [UploadHandler, ThumbnailHandler]
    handler = handlers[0]()
    for next_handler in handlers[1:]:
        handler.set_next(next_handler())

    @staticmethod
    def get_file_extension(mimetype: str):
        return mimetypes.guess_extension(mimetype)

    @staticmethod
    def upload_file(file_id: str, file: bytes, mimetype: str):
        file_bytes = base64.b64encode(file)
        extension = FileService.get_file_extension(mimetype)

        FileService.handler.handle((file_id, extension, file_bytes))
```

tasks.py

```py
import base64

from celery import shared_task
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from services.grpc_client import Client
from common.chain import AbstractHandler
from storage.models import File


def next_status(file: File):
    file.status += 1
    file.save()


def update_file_status(func):
    def wrapper(self, request):
        file_id, *args = request

        file_object = File.objects.get(id=file_id)

        next_status(file_object)
        return func(self, request)

    return wrapper


class UploadAbstractHandler(AbstractHandler):
    @staticmethod
    def get_file(file_id: str):
        return File.objects.get(id=file_id)

    @staticmethod
    def get_file_data(content: bytes, decode=False):
        if decode:
            content = base64.b64decode(content.decode(encoding="utf-8"))

        file_data = ContentFile(content)
        return file_data


class UploadHandler(UploadAbstractHandler):
    @staticmethod
    @shared_task
    def handle_file_upload(file_id: str, extension: str, content: bytes):
        file = UploadAbstractHandler.get_file(file_id)

        file_data = UploadAbstractHandler.get_file_data(content, decode=True)
        file.file.save(f"{file.id}.{extension}", file_data)

    @update_file_status
    def handle(self, request):
        file_id, extension, content = request

        self.handle_file_upload.delay(file_id, extension, content)
        return super().handle(request)


class ThumbnailHandler(UploadAbstractHandler):
    @staticmethod
    @shared_task
    def handle_thumbnail_generation(file_id: str, content: bytes):
        file = UploadAbstractHandler.get_file(file_id)
        file_data = UploadAbstractHandler.get_file_data(content, decode=True)

        try:
            value = Client(settings.GRPC_ADDR).generate_thumbnail(file_data.read())

            file_data = UploadAbstractHandler.get_file_data(value, decode=False)

            file.thumbnail.save(f"{file.id}_thumb.png", file_data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    @update_file_status
    def handle(self, request):
        file_id, _, content = request
        self.handle_thumbnail_generation.delay(file_id, content)
        return super().handle(request)
```

serializers.py

````py
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = [
            "id",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
            "name",
            "group",
            "description",
            "tags",
            "status",
            "file",
            "size",
            "thumbnail",
        ]
        read_only_fields = [
            "id",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
            "status",
            "size",
            "thumbnail",
        ]

    def _get_file_ext(self, name: str):
        return name.split(".")[-1]

    def _get_valid_filename(self, name: str, file_obj):
        ext_from_file = self._get_file_ext(file_obj.name)

        if not name.lower().endswith(ext_from_file.lower()):
            name = f"{name}.{ext_from_file}"

        return name

    def validate(self, attrs):
        for key in attrs:
            if attrs[key] == "":
                attrs[key] = None
            if attrs[key] == [""]:
                attrs[key] = []

        attrs["name"] = self._get_valid_filename(attrs["name"], attrs["file"])

        return super().validate(attrs)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.validated_data.pop("file")
        return super().save(**kwargs)
``` I pop file in serializer to handle file upload in celery task
````

Comment: where exactly are you saving file info to db, you are not passing anything related to file to FileSerializer

Comment: @iklinac, ig file.file.save(), should do that. When i remove `ThumbnailHandler` from `FileService.handlers` it does work fine. When there are both it only saves thumbnail, and file field is empty even tho i can see file is in my physical storage.

[both files in storage screenshot](https://prnt.sc/SAKEz_l3GW6B), but only thumbnail is shown in response.
[response](https://mystb.in/OlympicsEngineerPmid)